# How to universalize a shortcut?

Tags: windows, file-shortcut

I made a game and I put all my code and executable in the `code` folder. I created a shortcut to the executable outside the folder so users won't have to dig in the folder to find the exe. Problem is the shortcut file path only works for me.

I uploaded the project to GitHub, so my file path starts from the downloads folder. So for my shortcut properties I tried

`"%userprofile%\Downloads\Space-Invaders-main\Code\Space Invaders.exe"` for target and

`%userprofile%\Downloads\Space-Invaders-main\Code` for start in.

My friend tried it, but he got this [error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TBMFM.png).

How can I make a file path so any user from any computer can run the shortcut?

Comment: You can’t because you don’t know where they will put the executable files. This kind of thing is done with an installer.

Comment: Or, are you saying you have a shortcut in a top level folder `code` that executed a file in a sub folder? In that case, use a relative path. Not an absolute path. The executable you are running is “relative” to the code folder. You don’t have to know where the code folder is, you just need to know where the executable is in relation to the code folder. If you’re in the code folder, where the shortcut is, then the shortcut should point to `<subfolder>\<subfolder>\game.exe`

Comment: Create a folder and shortcut in the %All Users%  folder

Comment: @Appleoddity I tried `"Code\Space Invaders.exe"` for target and `Code` for start in, but I am getting an error that the file path is invalid. My shortcut is outside the code folder while the exe is. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: @Subham it is not possible to do what you ask. You have no way of knowing where the code folder is on someone else’s computer. You have to have an installer that puts the files in the user’s chosen location and builds the shortcuts relative to that. You’re making an assumption about someone else’s choices or configuration and it will not be reliable.

Comment: @Appleoddity I’ll just tell the user to not move the executable and code folder from the downloads folder. In that case, is what I’m asking possible if I do everything relative to the downloads folder?

Comment: @Subham yes. Then it works using the `%userprofile%` variable as you did. What error are you receiving? Please [edit] your post and add in more detail.

Comment: @Appleoddity I updated my question

Comment: You can create universal/portable shortcuts based on environmental variables such as `%UserProfile%\Downloads\etc., `but you have to do some editing of a `. lnk`file's bytes. I've posted details before on here or StackOverflow...

Answer (score 0):

Shortcuts do not support relative paths. It really is as simple as that. Developers commonly use Batch files (`.bat`) for what you describe.

However, I found an interesting alternative using Windows Explorer as an intermediate:

> 5. Under the “Shortcut” tab delete “C:\Windows” in “Start in” field to make it blank. This ensures that the shortcut will start in its current path.
> 6. In Target field add this: %windir%\explorer.exe. Following it, add the relative path to your program in double-quotes. For example, %windir%\explorer.exe "\your\folder\app.exe” or %windir%\explorer.exe "..\my\files"

[Source](https://sumtips.com/how-to/create-shortcut-with-relative-path-in-windows/)

You may still have icon trouble with this method, but this is the best you can do.

Comment: I tried this method, but now the exe can't find the files to make the game run. I looked at your source and tried the bat method, but similar issue.

Comment: So your program probably relies on its working directory instead of its location. You can fix that.

Comment: How do I fix that?

Comment: Would you please tell me what I can do?

Comment: I cannot. I don’t know any details about your game. Maybe `cd` to the directory inside your code.

Comment: The issue (and fix) with the answer above and its Source reference, is that the relative folder in your file needs to start with `".\"` not `"\"` or `"..\"`.

Comment: You can also click the `Change Icon...` button, browse to your exe, and choose the icon embedded in it. If you're linking to a document or some other similar file, you'll need to browse to the program which opens that file type to get the icon you want.

Answer (score 0):

This is a slightly different problem, but the solution may be of use.
I have a large collection of ePub (Book) files stored in a tree structure by genre and author name. [eg. Q:\SFF\B\Bloggs, Fred\Space Wars.epub].   When an author uses a number of pen-names, I put shortcuts in the author folder pointing to the alternate folders with the other names.  When I copied the entire Library to a portable hard drive, the shortcuts failed.
The solution was to create an Environment Variable "Z" with value of the original drive path [in this case "Q:\"] on the source PC.
Then right-click on the shortcut and select "Properties".
In the "Target" area, replace the Drive [in this case "Q:\"] with "%Z%" and save. [If the Environment variable does not complete a path to an existing file or folder, save will not work.]
When the portable drive is plugged into another PC, it could be assigned any drive letter. Set [or change] the value for the Environment Variable "Z" to the correct drive letter and then all the modified shortcuts will work.
I chose "Z" but the Environment variable could have any (unused) name. "%Z%" has the same number of characters as "Q:\" and I have not yet written a program to scan my library and modify all the shortcuts to relative - that's the next major project.

The following batch file "Z_Relative.bat" placed on the portable drive can be run to set the Environment Variable.

```
    @echo off
    REM Batch file to set the Environment Variable "Z" to the current drive.
    REM Place in root directory of USB drive to setup relative shortcuts 
    REM     WITHIN the drive if run from there.

    IF NOT %Z%==%CD% SETX Z %CD%
```

(This is required because %CD% only works in Command Prompts and won't work in a shortcut.)

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Please take the [tour] and read through the [help] center. Here is a guide on [ask] and [answer].

Answer (score 0):

You can make "universal"/portable/shareable shortcuts, but it requires editing the Windows-created binary `.lnk` file -- neither the com objects nor the IShellLink interface expose direct manipulation of the flags or selective exclusion/inclusion of data.

Start by downloading a copy of `[MS-SHLLINK].pdf` , the spec sheet for `.lnk` files. Take note of:

- The fact that all sections except for the ***Header*** and ***ExtraData(Terminal block)*** are optional, but a functioning link must also always have a target specified by either an ***IDLst*** or an ***EnvironmetProps*** path.
- The varous ***Linkflags*** and their functions

But when Windows creates a shortcut it will always have:

| Section | Element(s) |
| --- | --- |
| Header | LinkFlags, IconIndex, target attributes, RunAs, ShowWindow |
| IDList | Path rooted in shell namespace, ie. `This PC\C:\Windows` or `Libraries\Documents` |
| LinkInfo | VolumeID, UNC path, etc. |
| StringData | RelativePath, WorkingDirectory |
| ExtraData | TrackerProps, PropertyStore, EnvironemtProps (if target was specified with environmental variables) KnownFolder/SpecialFolder (if applicable) |

So machine-specific data exists in the ***LinkInfo***, ***TrackerProps***, and ***PropertyStore*** sections. All of these can be removed and the link will remain functional.

If the target was specified with environmental variables, that path is saved in the ***EnvironmentProp***s section, but the ***IDList*** will specify the expanded, time-of-creation-specific location -- and normally, when both are present, that takes precedence. for the ***EnvProps*** path to take precedence, the ***IDList*** must be removed, the `HasLinkTargetIDList` flag cleared, and the `PreferEnvironmetPath` flag set. All Windows machines have a built-in example of this -- the "Command Prompt" shortcut in the **Start Menu**. If you view its **Propertoes** dialog, you see that both the target and "Start in" (***WorkingDirectory***) are specified with environmental variables:

[image]

More importantly, if you parse the ***LInkFlags*** ( code is coming... ), you see a combination of flags you won't see on any user-created shortcut:

```
C:\\\\\\\\\System Tools> (Get-LinkFlags -Path '.\Command Prompt.lnk').LinkFlags

HasName
HasRelativePath
HasWorkingDir
HasIconLocation
IsUnicode
ForceNoLinkInfo
HasExpString
PreferEnvironmentPath
```

If a user creates a shortcut with te same variables, the ***LinkFLags*** will be:

```
HasLinkTargetIDList
HasLinkInfo
HasName
HasRelativePath
HasWorkingDir
IsUnicode
HasExpString
EnableTargetMetadata
```

And to remove blocks like ***IDList*** and ***LinkInfo***, as well as set/clear the corresponding ***LinkFlags***, we have to hack away at the bytes in the `.lnk` file.

So, whether the target is specified by ***EnvProps*** or ***IDList***, you always want to:

- Remove the ***LinkInfo***, ***TrackerProps***, and ***PropStoreProps*** blocks, as well as ***KnownFolder/SpecialFolde***` blocks if present.
- Clear the `HasLinkInfo` and `EnableTargetMetadata` flags.
- Set the `ForceNoLinkInfo`, `ForceNoLinkTrack`, and `DisableKnownFolderTracking` flags.

But first, you want to create a shortcut to work with, which means determining the best path for your purposes. ***EnvProps*** paths are best for locations like ***%AppData%***, and can be created via the **New Shortcut** wizard or the *wscript.shell* com object.

But for a folder like ***Downloads***, ***%UserProfile\Downloads%*** will fail if the user has redirected their ***Downloads*** folder. A better way to specify the folder is an ***IDList*** that correspons to:

- ***This PC\Downloads***

because it will be valid even for a redirected Downloads folder.

The best way to ensure you have the desired ***IDList*** path is to navigate to the target in ***Explorer***, paying attention to the Address bar, and then using the context menu `Create shortcut` command. This will ensure you don't end up with an ***IDList*** that specifies ***This PC\C:\Users\UserProfileFolder\Downloads***. Because the **Properies** dialog will display the identical file-system path for both.

After creation, you can modify ***Description***, ***WindowStyle***, and ***RunAs*** via the **Properties** dialog, but you have to use the com object if you want to specify an icon location with environmental variables  or, as I usually do, set the seemingly useless ***RelativePath*** to `$null`, which clears the corresponding flag as well when saved.

Now its time to do the diry work of byte manipualtion, determining block offsets, and removing selected blocks (fortunately, this is an exercise in subtraction rather than addition). For this, I wrote the following **PowerShell** code.

```
###   LinkFlags enum   ########################################################################################
Try {                               ###   Try/Catch to suppress TypeExists error when run more than once in the same session
    Add-Type -TypeDefinition @'
    using System;
    [FlagsAttribute]
    public enum LinkFlags : uint {
        HasLinkTargetIDList         = 0x00000001,               HasLinkInfo                 = 0x00000002,
        HasName                     = 0x00000004,               HasRelativePath             = 0x00000008,
        HasWorkingDir               = 0x00000010,               HasArguments                = 0x00000020,
        HasIconLocation             = 0x00000040,               IsUnicode                   = 0x00000080,
        ForceNoLinkInfo             = 0x00000100,               HasExpString                = 0x00000200,
        RunInSeparateProcess        = 0x00000400,               HasDarwinID                 = 0x00001000,
        RunAsUser                   = 0x00002000,               HasExpIcon                  = 0x00004000,
        NoPidlAlias                 = 0x00008000,               RunWithShimLayer            = 0x00020000,
        ForceNoLinkTrack            = 0x00040000,               EnableTargetMetadata        = 0x00080000,
        DisableLinkPathTracking     = 0x00100000,               DisableKnownFolderTracking  = 0x00200000,
        DisableKnownFolderAlias     = 0x00400000,               AllowLinkToLink             = 0x00800000,
        UnaliasOnSave               = 0x01000000,               PreferEnvironmentPath       = 0x02000000,
        KeepLocalIDListForUNCTarget = 0x04000000
    }
'@
} Catch {}

###   StringData LinkFlag/ValueName dictionary   #############################################################
#
$StringDataID = [Ordered]@{
    HasName                 = 'NameString';             HasRelativePath         = 'RelativePath'
    HasWorkingDir           = 'WorkingDir';             HasArguments            = 'CommandLineArguments'
    HasIconLocation         = 'IconLocation'
}

[String]$StringDataFlags            = $StringDataID.Keys -join '|'   ###   Regex to test for StringData   ####

###   ExtraData blockName/Signature dictionary   #############################################################
#
$ExtraDataSig = @{
    CONSOLE_PROPS                   = [UInt32]'0xA0000002';     CONSOLE_FE_PROPS        = [UInt32]'0xA0000004'
    DARWIN_PROPS                    = [UInt32]'0xA0000006';     ENVIRONMENT_PROPS       = [UInt32]'0xA0000001'
    ICON_ENVIRONMENT_PROPS          = [UInt32]'0xA0000007';     KNOWN_FOLDER_PROPS      = [UInt32]'0xA000000B'
    PROPERTY_STORE_PROPS            = [UInt32]'0xA0000009';     SHIM_PROPS              = [UInt32]'0xA0000008'
    SPECIAL_FOLDER_PROPS            = [UInt32]'0xA0000005';     TRACKER_PROPS           = [UInt32]'0xA0000003'
    VISTA_AND_ABOVE_IDLIST_PROPS    = [UInt32]'0xA000000C'
}

###   Constants and supporting objects   #####################################################################

$HeaderSize             = 0x4c
$FlagsOffset            = 0x14
$ASCIIEncoder           = [System.Text.Encoding]::GetEncoding('ASCII')
$UniEncoder             = [System.Text.Encoding]::GetEncoding('Unicode')

###   Utility functions   ####################################################################################

##############################################################################################################

Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms

Function Get-PathViaDialog {
    $OPenDlg = [System.WIndows.Forms.OpenFileDialog]::new()
    $OpenDlg.Title              = 'Select shortcut to modify'
    $OpenDlg.Filter             = 'Shortcut files (*.lnk)|*.lnk|All files (*.*)|*.*'
    $OpenDlg.DefaultExt         = '.lnk'
    $OpenDlg.DereferenceLinks   = $true
    $OpenDlg.InitialDirectory   = 'shell:Desktop'
    If ($OpenDlg.ShowDialog()) {
        $OpenDlg.FileName
    } Else {
        ''
}}

Function Save-ViaDialog {
    Param(
        [Byte[]]$ShLinkBytes,
        [String]$InitialDirectory
    )
    $SaveDlg       = [System.Windows.Forms.SaveFileDialog]::new()
    $SaveDlg.Title              = 'Save as...'
    $SaveDlg.Filter             = "Shortcut files (*.lnk)|*.lnk|All files (*.*)|*.*"
    $SaveDlg.AddExtension       = $true
    $SaveDlg.DefaultExt         = '.lnk'
    $SaveDlg.DereferenceLinks   = $true
    $SaveDlg.InitialDirectory   = $(If ($InitialDirectory) {$InitialDirectory} Else {'shell:Desktop'})
    If ($SaveDlg.ShowDialog())
    {
        [System.IO.File]::WriteAllBytes($SaveDlg.FileName , $ShLinkBytes)
        ###   Returnnvalue
        $SaveDlg.FileName
}}

###   Get-LinkFlags   ########################################################################################
#   Retrieve flags from .lnk file or Byte[]
#
Function Get-LinkFlags {
    param(
        [Alias('FullName')]
        [Parameter(Mandatory, Position=0, ParameterSetName='FromFile', ValueFromPipeline, ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName)]
        [String[]]$Path,
        [Parameter(Mandatory, Position=0, ParameterSetName='FromBytes')]
        [Byte[]]$LinkBytes
    )
    Process {
        If ($PSCmdlet.ParameterSetName -eq 'FromFile')
        {
            ForEach ($p in @($Path)) {
                @((Resolve-Path $p).Path) | ForEach {
                    $lnkFileInfo        = Get-item $_
                    [PSCustomObject]@{
                        'Name'          = $lnkFileInfo.Name
                        'LinkFlags'     = [LinkFlags]([BitConverter]::ToUInt32(([IO.File]::ReadAllBytes($_)), $FlagsOffset)) -split ', '
                        'FullName'      = $lnkFileInfo.FullName
        }}}}
        Else {
            [LinkFlags]([BitConverter]::ToUInt32($LinkBytes, $FlagsOffset))
}}}

###   Set-LinkFlags   ########################################################################################
#   Update the LinkFlags in a file or Byte[] by setting (-Raise) or clearing specified flags.
#
Function Set-LinkFlags  {
    param(
        [Parameter(Mandatory, Position=0, ParameterSetName='InByteArray')]
        [Byte[]]$ShLinkBytes,
        [Parameter(Mandatory, Position=0, ParameterSetName='InFile')]
        [String]$Path,
        [LinkFlags]$Raise,
        [LinkFlags]$Clear
    )
    Begin   {
        If ($PSCmdlet.ParameterSetName -eq 'InFile') {
            $ShLinkBytes = [System.IO.File]::ReadAllBytes($Path)
        }
        [LinkFlags]$currFlags = [LinkFlags]([BitConverter]::ToUInt32($ShLinkBytes, $FlagsOffset))
    }
    Process {
        [BitConverter]::GetBytes((($currFlags -bor $Raise -band (-bnot $Clear))).Value__) |
          ForEach -Begin { $i = $FlagsOffset } -Process {
              $ShLinkBytes[($i++)] = $_
          } -End {}
    }
    End     {
        If ($PSCmdlet.ParameterSetName -eq 'InFile') {
            [System.IO.File]::WriteAllBytes($Path, $ShLinkBytes)
}}}

###   Get-ExtraDataIndex   ######################################################################################
#   Use the regular expression engine to locate the signature bytes of
#   all ExtraData blocks present in the ShellLInk.
#   If found, return name, offset, and size of the block(s).
#
Function Get-ExtraDataIndex {
    Param(
        [Byte[]]$SHLinkBytes
    )
    $LinkBYtesAsString  = $ASCIIEncoder.GetString($SHLinkBytes)
    $BlockIndex         = $ExtraDataSig.Keys | ForEach {
        $BlockOffset    = [Regex]::new([Regex]::Escape($ASCIIEncoder.GetString([BitConverter]::GetBytes($ExtraDataSig[$_])))).Match($LinkBYtesAsString).Index - 4
        If ($BlockOffset -gt 0) {
            [PSCustomObject]@{
                'Name'     = $_
                'Offset'   = $BlockOffset
                'Size'     = [BitConverter]::ToUInt32($SHLinkBytes, $BlockOffset)
    }}}
    Write-Verbose ($BlockIndex | select Name, @{n='0xOffset';e={'0x{0:x4}' -f $_.Offset}}, @{n='0xSize';e={'0x{0:x4}' -f $_.Size}} | Out-String)
    $BlockIndex
}

###   New-RoamingShortcut   ####################################################################################
#   Create a modified copy of an existing shortcut with the LinkInfo and TrackerProps sections removed,
#   as well as KnownFolderProps and SpecialFolderProps if they exist.
#   Optionally:
#       - If the shortcut has an EnvironmentProps block, set the PreferEnvironmentPath flag and remove the IDList.
#       - Un-alias paths so file system path is always displalyed.
#       - Remove the PropertyStore and clear the EnableTargetMetadata flag.
#
Function New-RoamingShortcut {
    Param(
        [Parameter(Position=0)]
        [ValidateScript({(Test-Path $_ -PathType Leaf) -and ($_ -match '\.lnk$')})]
        [String]$SourcePath,
        [Parameter(Position=1)]
        [ValidateScript({Test-Path $_ -IsValid})]
        [String]$OutFile,
        [Switch]$PreferEnvironMentPath,
        [Switch]$UnAliasPath,
        [Switch]$NoMetadata
    )
    # Initialize variables to null.
    [UInt32]$IDListOffset   = [UInt32]$IDListSize =
        [UInt32]$LinkInfoOffset = [UInt32]$LinkInfoSize =
                                    [UInt32]$StringDataOffset= $null

    If ( ! $SourcePath ) {
        $SourcePath             = Get-PathViaDialog
    } Else {
        $SourcePath           = (Resolve-Path $SourcePath).Path
    }
    
    $LinkBytes                  = [System.IO.File]::ReadAllBytes($SourcePath)
    [LinkFlags]$LinkFlags       = Get-LinkFlags $LinkBytes
    Write-Verbose "LinkFlags :`n$(@(@($LinkFlags -split ', ').ForEach{'{1,14}{0}' -f $_,' ' }) -join "`n")"
    
    $currOffset   = $HeaderSize
    Switch -Regex   ($LinkFLags)
    {
        'HasLinkTargetIDList'
        {
            $IDListOffset       = $currOffset
            $IDListSize         = 2 + [BitConverter]::ToUInt16($LinkBytes, $currOffset)
            $currOffset        += $IDListSize
        }
        'HasLinkInfo'
        {
            $LinkInfoOffset     = $currOffset
            $LinkInfoSize       = [BitConverter]::ToUInt32($LinkBytes, $currOffset)
            $currOffset        += $LinkInfoSize
        }
        $StringDataFlags
        {
            $StringDataOffset   = $currOffset
        }
    }
    $ExtraDataIndex             = Get-ExtraDataIndex $LinkBytes | sort Offset
    If ($StringDataOffset) {
        $StringDataSize         = $ExtraDataIndex[0].Offset - $StringDataOffset
    }
    $ExcludedBlocks             = 'Special|Known|Tracker'
    If ($NoMetadata)  { $ExcludedBlocks += '|Property' }
    
    ###   Construct New ShellLink   ###
    
    If ($PreferEnvironmentPath -and ($LinkFlags -match 'HasExpString')) {
        $IDListSize             =   $null
    }
    [Byte[]]$NewLink       = [Byte[]](
                                    $LinkBytes[0..($HeaderSize-1)] +
                                    $(If ($IDListSize)     {$LinkBytes[$IDListOffset..($IDListSize-1+$IDListOffset)]} )     +
                                    $(If ($StringDataSize) {$LinkBytes[$StringDataOffset..($StringDataSize - 1 + $StringDataOffset)]} ) +
                                    $($ExtraDataIndex | ? Name -notMatch $ExcludedBlocks | ForEach {$LinkBytes[$_.Offset..($_.Size - 1 + $_.Offset)]}) +
                                    [Byte[]]::new(4)
    )
    Set-LinkFlags $NewLink -Raise 'ForceNoLinkInfo, ForceNoLinkTrack, DisableKnownFolderTracking' -Clear 'HasLinkInfo'
    If ($PreferEnvironmentPath -and ($LinkFlags -match 'HasExpString')) {
        Set-LinkFlags $NewLink -Raise 'PreferEnvironmentPath' -Clear 'HasLinktargetIDList'
    }
    If ($UnAliasPath) {
        Set-LinkFlags $NewLink -Raise 'NoPidlAlias,DisableKnownFolderAlias,UnaliasOnSave'
    }
    If ($NoMetadata) {
        Set-LinkFlags $NewLink -Clear 'EnableTargetMetaData'
    }
    Write-Verbose "New LinkFlags :`n$(@(@((Get-LinkFlags $NewLink) -split ', ').ForEach{'{1}{0}' -f $_, (' ' * 14)}) -join "`n")"
    If ($OutFile) {
        If (! [IO.Path]::IsPathRooted($OutFile)) {   ### Convert relative path to fully-qualified path
            $OutFile    = Join-Path (Resolve-Path (Split-Path $OutFile)).Path (Split-Path $OutFile -Leaf)
        }
        [System.IO.File]::WriteAllBytes($OutFIle , $NewLink)
    } Else {
        $OutFile = Save-ViaDialog -ShLinkBytes $NewLink -InitialDirectory (Split-Path $SourcePath)
    }
    If (Test-Path $OutFile) {
        Write-Verbose ('New shortcut saved to "{0}".' -f $OutFIle)
    }
}
```

### *...Instructions and examples forthcoming -- but posed to make sure I ddn't lose all the work thus far...*

Answer (score 0):

There are some functions from the days of DOS that still persist in Windows 10 and will work just as well updated, when running old apps in new Windows. So digging out the space invaders my 5 year old daughter requested 1/4 of a century ago, I tried to run it as a portable app.

This seems to work well. Modern syntax is command /c "command" but `%comspec% /r` is still viable in a local folder. One issue is the screen forces Windows 10 into fullscreen 640 x 480 but the action and sound effects are just as entertaining 25 years later.

[image]

### Now the Answer

Here I sent it to a remote mapped drive (as a zip, and it could be to an USB thumb or Floppy Disk or email) and here it is unTARed over there.

I deleted my local copy to ensure it was not found.

**Any yes when I click on that remote short-cut** it still runs without any error.

[image]

```
Target: %comspec% /r "Start " " ".\code\SpaceInvaders.exe"
start in: "%windir%\explorer.exe .\code"
```

Note that even a shortcut like this will be flagged as a False Positive by VirusTotal as it matches how some exploits have been written !!

So I have not published the EXE as its compiled basic from 24 years ago. However If you "Trust Me" and want to see how it worked here is the new bundled version with modified short-cut.
https://github.com/GitHubRulesOK/MyNotes/raw/master/Hogwartz.zip
[image]